# OsError in virtual box snakemake pipeline for array-analysis

Tags: linux, snakemake

The rule is written for calling genotypes using array analysis cli for illumina gsa chips.

```py
import configparser
config=configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(".//config")
homepath=config.get('Paths','home_dir')
inputpath=config.get('Paths','input_dir')
outputpath=config.get('Paths','output_dir')
Sentrix_ids=config.items('Sentrix_ids')
sentrixids=[]
positions=['R01C01','R01C02',
                        'R02C01','R02C02',
                        'R03C01','R03C02',
                        'R04C01','R04C02',
                        'R05C01','R05C02',
                        'R06C01','R06C02',
                        'R07C01','R07C02',
                        'R08C01','R08C02',
                        'R09C01','R09C02',
                        'R10C01','R10C02',
                        'R11C01','R11C02',
                        'R12C01','R12C02']

rule all:
        input:
                expand(outputpath+"/{sids}_{pos}.gtc",sids=sentrixids,pos=positions)

rule idat2vcf:
        input:
                idatpath=homepath+"/ss.csv",
                clusterfile=homepath+"/input/"+"GSA-24v3-0_A1_ClusterFile.egt",
          manifestfile=homepath+"/input/"+"GSA-24v3-0_A1.bpm"

        output:
                outputfol=outputpath+"/"+"gtcfiles"
        shell:
                "bash /scripts/idattogtc.sh {input.idatpath} {input.clusterfile} {input.manifestfile} {output.outputfol}"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
exec_path="/home/user14/Downloads/array-analysis-cli-linux-x64-v2.1.0/array-
analysis-cli/array-analysis-cli"
idat_path=$1
cluster_file=$2
manifest_file=$3
output_fol=$4
${exec_path} genotype call \
  --bpm-manifest ${manifest_file} \
  --cluster-file ${cluster_file} \
  --idat-sample-sheet ${idat_path} \
  --output-folder ${output_fol}
```

When I run snakemake, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user14/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 469, in snakemake
    force_use_threads=use_threads)
  File "/home/user14/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 447, in execute
    self.persistence.cleanup_shadow()
  File "/home/user14/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/persistence.py", line 128, in cleanup_shadow
    shutil.rmtree(self.shadow_path)
  File "/home/user14/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 490, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/user14/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: '/media/sf_vm_centfiles/workflow/.snakemake/shadow'
```

Comment: Are you running Snakemake within a shared folder in Virtual Box by any chance?  [Here's somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889859) with what sounds like a similar problem.